# How does Instagram API Re-submission?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, submission

How does Instagram API do Re-submission?

We applied Instagram API and That is already passed.
we have selected "My app allows people to login with Instagram and share their own content." in "1. Which use case best describes your Instagram integration?" questtion when we applied.
But This is a mistakes. Actually We wanted to select "My product helps brands and advertisers understand, manage their audience and media rights." in this question.

So we want to re-submit on Instagram API.
We tryed submittion again, and then get this message "You have not requested any permission."

So can you help me to solve this problem ?